# WPF DockPanel - order controls

Tags: c#, wpf, dockpanel

I want a TextBox with line numbers. So I decided to use one small TextBox for the line numbers on the left and another big one on the right for the text. 
My problem now is that I put these two TextBoxes into a Dockpanel and I need a height difference because the TextBox for the line numbers should not have scrollbars. So I need to shorten the left TextBox. My plan is to put an empty StackPanel below the left TextBox. And I'm getting trouble because the DockPanel doesn't sort my controls like I want. The only way I got it was using a fix width but I don't want that!

[image]

Or should I go a complete different way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have to build this control, but you can find something similar for WPF. See this link [AvalonEdit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor). It's a text editor control.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a scroll bar on a control, just set the VerticalScrollBarVisibility to disabled.

But I'm not sure that's exactly what you need. If you do this then obviously your line numbers aren't going to scroll with your text box. You best bet might be to put your two textboxes (although if the line numbers aren't supposed to be editable, you might want to use labels instead) in a dockpanel and wrap the dock panel in a scrollviewer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use ScrollView. The code below demonstrates the idea. But I haven't come up with a solution to enable horizontal scrolling.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Height="100">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <TextBlock.Inlines>
                        1<LineBreak/>
                        2<LineBreak/>
                        3<LineBreak/>
                        4<LineBreak/>
                        5<LineBreak/>
                        6<LineBreak/>
                        7<LineBreak/>
                        8<LineBreak/>
                        9<LineBreak/>
                        10<LineBreak/>
                        11<LineBreak/>
                        12<LineBreak/>
                        13<LineBreak/>
</TextBlock.Inlines>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    I want a TextBox with line numbers. So I decided to use one small TextBox for the line numbers on the left and another big one on the rigth for the text. My problem now is that I put these two TextBoxes into a Dockpanel and I need a Heigth difference because the TextBox for the line numbers should not have scrollbars. So I need to short the left TextBox. My plan is to put an empty StackPanel below the left TextBox. And I'm getting trouble because the DockPanel doesen't sort my controls like i want. The only way I got it was using a fix width but I don't want that!
                </TextBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

It looks like
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: er...It is possiblly duplicate from Matt Burland's answer.... I didn't read all the answers.